# Firebase deploy Error: Compilation error in y: [E] 1:1 - mismatched input '{' expecting {'function', 'service', 'rules_version'}

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to deploy my google action webhook fulfilment but it leads to the following error related to google cloud firestore. I have the database rules to 'test mode'.
**CMD code snip included**

```
=== Deploying to 'grievance-redressal-syst-50e4d'...

i  deploying firestore, functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint E:\programming\AOG\grievance-redressal-syst-50e4d\functions
> eslint .

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  firestore: checking y for compilation errors...
i  firestore: reading indexes from y...

Error: Compilation error in y:
[E] 1:1 - mismatched input '{' expecting {'function', 'service', 
'rules_version'}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. delete all firestore related files and delete the y file
2. run firestore init again -> will create the files again
3. run firestore deploy again

worked for me